# Perl mechanize print HTML form names

Tags: html, forms, perl, mechanize

I'm trying to automate hotmail login. How can I find what the appropriate fields are? When I print the forms I just get a bunch of hex information.

what's the correct method and how is it used?

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP::UserAgent;


my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url = "http://hotmail.com";
$mech->get($url);



print "Forms: $mech->forms";


if ($mech->success()){
    print "Successful Connection\n";
} else {
    print "Not a successful connection\n"; }
```

Comment: And how does that hex stuff look like?

Comment: If I open hotmail.com in my Firefox with JavaScript turned off, I get redirected to https://login.live.com/jsDisabled.srf?mkt=EN-US&lc=1033, which says `Microsoft account requires JavaScript to sign in. This web browser either does not support JavaScript, or scripts are being blocked.`. Try using a tool like Firebug to look at what is actually being POSTed. I'm not sure you can emulte it easily.

Comment: @simbabque ARRAY(0x306b018)

Comment: `$mech->forms` returns an array reference. You're not very familiar with Perl, are you? Try this: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $mech->forms;`. It will show you the content of the array ref in a more readable format. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html for more on references.

Comment: Isn't [hotmail replaced by outlook](https://www.google.com/search?q=hotmail+replaced+by+outlook)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Data::Dumper;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $url = "http://yoururl.com";

$mech->get($url);

my @forms = $mech->forms;

foreach my $form (@forms) {

        my @inputfields = $form->param;

        print Dumper \@inputfields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is useful to look at what the web site is asking in advance of coding up a reader or interface to it.
I wrote this bookmarklet that you save in your browser bookmarks and when you click it while visiting any html web page will show in a pop-up all the forms actions and fields with values even hidden. Simply copy the text below and paste into a new bookmark location field, name it and save.

`javascript:t=%22<TABLE%20BORDER='1'%20BGCOLOR='#B5D1E8'>%22;for(i=0;i<document.forms.length;i++){t+=%22<TR><TH%20colspan='4'%20align='left'%20BGCOLOR='#336699'>%22;t+=%22<FONT%20color='#FFFFFF'>%20Form%20Name:%20%22;t+=document.forms[i].name;t+=%22</FONT></TH></TR>%22;t+=%22<TR><TH%20colspan='4'%20align='left'%20BGCOLOR='#99BADD'>%22;t+=%22<FONT%20color='#FFFFFF'>%20Form%20Action:%20%22;t+=document.forms[i].action;t+=%22</FONT></TH></TR>%22;t+=%22<TR><TH%20colspan='4'%20align='left'%20BGCOLOR='#99BADD'>%22;t+=%22<FONT%20color='#FFFFFF'>%20Form%20onSubmit:%20%22;t+=document.forms[i].onSubmit;t+=%22</FONT></TH></TR>%22;t+=%22<TR><TH>ID:</TH><TH>Element%20Name:</TH><TH>Type:</TH><TH>Value:</TH></TR>%22;for(j=0;j<document.forms[i].elements.length;j++){t+=%22<TR%20BGCOLOR='#FFFFFF'><TD%20align='right'>%22;t+=document.forms[i].elements[j].id;t+=%22</TD><TD%20align='right'>%22;t+=document.forms[i].elements[j].name;t+=%22</TD><TD%20align='left'>%20%22;t+=document.forms[i].elements[j].type;t+=%22</TD><TD%20align='left'>%20%22;if((document.forms[i].elements[j].type==%22select-one%22)%20||%20(document.forms[i].elements[j].type==%22select-multiple%22)){t_b=%22%22;for(k=0;k<document.forms[i].elements[j].options.length;k++){if(document.forms[i].elements[j].options[k].selected){t_b+=document.forms[i].elements[j].options[k].value;t_b%20+=%20%22%20/%20%22;t_b+=document.forms[i].elements[j].options[k].text;t_b+=%22%20%22;}}t+=t_b;}else%20if%20(document.forms[i].elements[j].type==%22checkbox%22){if(document.forms[i].elements[j].checked==true){t+=%22True%22;}else{t+=%22False%22;}}else%20if(document.forms[i].elements[j].type%20==%20%22radio%22){if(document.forms[i].elements[j].checked%20==%20true){t+=document.forms[i].elements[j].value%20+%20%22%20-%20CHECKED%22;}else{t+=document.forms[i].elements[j].value;}}else{t+=document.forms[i].elements[j].value;}t+=%22</TD></TR>%22;}}t+=%22</TABLE>%22;mA='menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,height=800,width=600,alwaysRaised=yes';nW=window.open(%22/empty.html%22,%22Display_Vars%22,%20mA);nW.document.write(t);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to mimc the post request that sends your login info, but the web site seems to be dynamically adding a bunch of id's ---long generated strings etc to the url and I couldn't figure out how to imitate them. So I wrote the hacky work-around below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;
use Data::Dumper;
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

#this is the name and complete path to the new html file we will create
my $new_html_file = 'XXXXXXXXX';
my $password = 'XXXXXXXX';
my $login = 'XXXXXXXXX';

#escape the .
$login =~ s/\./\\./g;

my $html_to_insert = qq(<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">setTimeout('testme()', 3400);function testme(){document.getElementById('res_box').innerHTML = '<h3 class="auto_click_login_np">Logging in...</h3>';document.f1.passwd.value = '$password';document.f1.login.value = '$login';\$("#idSIButton9").trigger("click");}var counter = 5;setInterval('countdown()', 1000);function countdown(){document.getElementById('res_box').innerHTML = '<h3 class="auto_click_login_np">You should be logged in within ' + counter + ' seconds</h3>';counter--;}</script><h2 style="background-color:#004c00; color: #fff; padding: 4px;" id="res_box" onclick="testme()" class="auto_click_login">If you are not logged in after a few seconds, click here.</h2>);

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
my $url = 'https://login.live.com';
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $url);

# A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
my $response_body;

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, \$response_body);

open( my $fresh_html_handle, '+>', 'fresh_html_from_login_page.html');


# Starts the actual request
my $curl_return_code = $curl->perform;

# Looking at the results...
if ($curl_return_code == 0) {
        print("Transfer went ok\n");
        my $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        # judge result and next action based on $response_code

        print $fresh_html_handle $response_body;

   } else {
        # Error code, type of error, error message
        print("An error happened: $curl_return_code ".$curl->strerror($curl_return_code)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n");
}
  close($fresh_html_handle);   


 #erase whatever a pre-existing edited file if there is one
 open  my $erase_html_handle, ">", $new_html_file or die "Hork! $!\n";
 print $erase_html_handle;
 close $erase_html_handle;




#open the file with the login page html
open( FH, '<', 'fresh_html_from_login_page.html');  

open( my $new_html_handle, '>>', $new_html_file);

my $tracker=0;

  while( <FH> ){



      if( $_ =~ /DOCTYPE/){
         $tracker=1;
         print $new_html_handle $_;

     } elsif($_ =~ /<\/body><\/html>/){
         #now add the javascript and html to automatically log the user in
         print $new_html_handle "$html_to_insert\n$_";
      }elsif( $tracker == 1){
         print $new_html_handle $_;
      }


 } 
  close(FH);           
  close($new_html_handle);

   my $sys_call_res = system("firefox file:///usr/bin/outlook_auto_login.html");
   print "\n\nresult: $sys_call_res\n\n";
```